# Receive Multipart FormData - Jersey 1.19.1 REST

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, jersey-1.0

I am sending `multipart/form-data` request but I am unable to get `FormData` values in Jersey 1.19.1 as `@FormDataParam` is not available. I am trying with the following code but I got strucked. Is there a way to resolve it in this Jersey version?

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadfile")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String uploadFile(@Context HttpContext hc) {
   HttpRequestContext request = hc.getRequest();

   return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need this extension: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-multipart

i think in thex 1.x jersey universe this was seperated.

here is an example blog post:

https://puspendu.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/restful-webservice-file-upload-with-jersey/

https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Comment: i have added `jersey-bundle-1.19.1.jar`. still the `jersey-multipart` should be added as a separate jar?

Comment: I didn't check. here is a blog post describing howto do uploads. maybe it is worth a try. maybe the multipart jar is for the client not for the server. but not 100% sure (https://puspendu.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/restful-webservice-file-upload-with-jersey/)

Comment: I am using `fetch` method in `React JS` project for AJAX calls. For backend only, i am using Java

Comment: The example for the server part seems good anyway, maybe you can give it a try

Comment: ya but that `@FormDataParam` annotation is not available in Jersey 1.19.1

Comment: that annotation is contained in the jersey-multipart, if you don't have it on the classpath, it is not contained in the bundle :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157571/discussion-between-sorontur-and-abraham-gnanasingh).